# Why does "0" start with "\x1d" on .Net Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, unicode

On .Net Framework, `"0".StartsWith("\x1d")` evaluates to `false`. ([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/m3uWM9))

On .Net Core 7, `"0".StartsWith("\x1d")` evaluates to `true`. ([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/05cKbm))

Why?!

<sub>**Note:** Yes, I understand I can use `string.StartsWith(char)` or `string.StartsWith(string, StringComparison.Ordinal)` to avoid this.  I'm asking why this code changed in behavior.</sub>

Comment: Likely due to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/string-comparison-net-5-plus). In short, Framework and Core use different logic for localized string comparison. A control character like `\x1d` is considered empty by one for purposes of comparison, not empty by the other.